# Finding specific value in a text file in java

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm currently practicing file handling in Java so I tried to create a method that will encode user inputs on a file using `writeUTF()` and other write functions.

My code looks like this :

```
public static void writeInfo(File file, int id, String name, int age) throws FileNotFoundException{
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new
            BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)));
    try{
        dataOut.writeInt(id);
        dataOut.writeUTF(name);
        dataOut.writeInt(age);
        dataOut.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.err.println("File not found !");
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println("Error writing in file !");
    }finally{
        try{
            dataOut.close();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    } 
}
```

Now my problem is that after having multiple inputs, I can't print out a specific set of values. For example, if I have 3 sets of input :

ID - 3
Name - Ace
Age - 20

ID - 8
Name - Marie
Age - 22

ID - 5
Name - Karl
Age - 25

If I want to find the set of inputs which has an ID value of 5, the output should be :

```
ID - 5
Name - Karl
Age - 25
```

But I always get an EndOfFileException after running.

This is the code how I find a specific value :

```
 public static void readID(File file, int id) throws FileNotFoundException{
    DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(new
        BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    try{
        while(dataIn.available()>0){
            if(dataIn.readInt() != id){
                dataIn.read();
                continue;
            }else{
                System.out.println("ID : " + dataIn.readInt());
                System.out.println("Name : " + dataIn.readUTF());
                System.out.println("Age : " + dataIn.readInt());
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found !");
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }finally{
        try{
            dataIn.close();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

I tried also different ways like containing the values I read first into a variable. I know that I'm doing something wrong and still finding up solutions over the net. But I hope you guys will help me so I can still learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
    while(dataIn.available()>0){
        if(dataIn.readInt() != id){ // <--- #1
            dataIn.read(); // <--- #2
            continue;
        }else{
            System.out.println("ID : " + dataIn.readInt()); // <-- #3
            System.out.println("Name : " + dataIn.readUTF());
            System.out.println("Age : " + dataIn.readInt());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

Line #1 will **consume** an `int` in the stream, if the `int` is what you want (if statement is `false`), `else` block is executed, but here `readInt` in line #3 will continuously read after the last `readInt`, which should be `name` field.

What's more, if the `if` statement is true, line #2 will read one `byte` and skip it, which is not enough for `name` field and `age` field.

So the following code may work:

```
while(dataIn.available()>0){
    int aId = dataIn.readInt();
    if(aId != id){
        dataIn.readUTF(); // skip name
        dataIn.readInt(); // skip age
        continue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("ID : " + aId);
        System.out.println("Name : " + dataIn.readUTF());
        System.out.println("Age : " + dataIn.readInt());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
while(dataIn.available()>0){
    int aId = dataIn.readInt();
    String name = dataIn.readUTF();
    int age = dataIn.readInt();

    if (aId == id) {
        System.out.println("ID : " + aId);
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + age);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```